# Sony Xperia M4: is the Sony bloatware installed on the system partition or the data partition?

Tags: insufficient-memory, sony-xperia

As detailed in my previous question ([How to upgrade a phone with only 8Gb. internal memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173097/how-to-upgrade-a-phone-with-only-8gb-internal-memory)), a relative of mine has a Sony Xperia M4 with Android 5.0 and only 8 Gb. of internal memory; after installing the few apps he uses, he has now only 320 Mb. of internal memory left.

Of course, the phone comes by default with all the Google bloatware **AND** all the Sony bloatware, and they can't be uninstalled by default. I'm considering rooting the phone to delete the unwanted apps, but this lead me to think: and what if all of the Sony bloatware is installed in `/system`, and deleting them doesn't free space in `/data`, which is where the space is needed?

So... does anyone know where are the Sony apps installed by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"can't be uninstalled by default" is a very obvious indicator that they're in `/system`.

You are correct about that deleting them won't free space for `/data` - unless you somehow find a way to repartition the storage and allocate more space for it, which is beyond normal users.

Comment: If you are comfortable enough to root a phone in order to remove bloatware then you should have no problem installing your relatives main apps as system apps, thus freeing up some data for other uses.

Comment: @arana Installing main apps to `/system` doesn't help when their updates still get installed to `/data`. Well, unless you are willing to manually keep the APKs in `/system` up-to-date.